# Wait for upload to complete before clicking a button

Tags: javascript, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I have a modal that opens to allow uploads.  The modal has a button for multi uploads, file to upload, upload, cancel, and ok (which you press after selecting the file, clicking the upload button, and then selecting ok to return to previous screen). Everything is working however this is a non angular app so it is not waiting for the upload to complete before selecting ok.  I put in a browser.driver.sleep which gives it enough time but I know this is an unreliable solution.  Any thoughts on how wait for the upload to finish before selecting ok?

The test code:

```
this.selectsUploadButton = function () {
    this.waitsForElementToBeClickable(uploadButton);
    uploadButton.click().then(function () {
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        uploadButtonOkLogo.click();
    });
};
```

the html: The error I am getting is not clickable due to the overlay.

```html
<div id="uploadLogoDialog" class="modal-dialog" style="display: block;">
  <div class="upload-overlay"></div>
  <div class="upload-logo-container">
    <div class="upload-logo-header">Image must be under 50 MB and in the following formats: .JPG, .GIF, .PNG</div>
    <div class="upload-logo-content">
      <div class="select-container">
        <button class="btn btn-select" data-bind="click: assosiateLogoImage">
          <span class="icon icon-select"></span>
          <span class="label">Select file</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-upload" data-bind="click: startLogoUpload, disable: logo.isUploaded" disabled="">
        <button class="btn btn-ok" data-bind="click: closeUploadLogoDialog">
          <div class="upload-progress-container">
            <div class="upload-progress" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: isUploading">
              <div class="progress-bar ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-bind="progressBar: { value: progressValue }" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="display: none; width: 0%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="percentage" data-bind="text: progressValue() + ' %'">0 %</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form id="uploadForm" action="https://iplan.preview.s3.amazonaws.com/" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadIFrame" method="post">
            <div class="file-input" data-bind="css: {'ie': isIE}">
              <input id="logoFile" type="file" data-bind="event:{ 'change': handleLogoSelection }" name="file">
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="upload-busy" data-bind="visible: isUploading" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any notification that gets generated once the upload has been completed? If so you can use it to wait until the notification appears on the page. Or if there is some uploading %, probably you can use that. Also can you please update the html code in your question too? Thanks

Comment: @Girish there is an upload bar and the upload button goes dark.

Comment: And what happens when upload action completes? Isnt there any notification for that?

Comment: @Girish no it just has that bar

Comment: Can you update the html code of the upload bar and upload button in your question?

Comment: @Girish I added the upload modal html the error protractor throws is shown as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option here is to wait until the upload button gets `disabled` using `wait()` function that protractor has along with `ExpectedConditions` object. `wait()` function always waits until the given condition is true, so you have to provide an argument in such a way that the it turns true after sometime (which should be your desired value). Here's how -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.elementToBeClickable(uploadButton)),10000).then(function(){
    uploadButtonOkLogo.click();
}); //Wait until element is not clickable (checks if element is enabled to decide if its clickable)
```

Alternatively you can write your own ExpectedCondition until element is not enabled and then use it in your wait function. Here's how -

```
browser.wait(function(){
    return uploadButton.isEnabled().then(function(enabled){
        return enabled === false;  // wait until element is disabled and if it is disabled then return true
    });
}, 10000).then(function(){
    uploadButtonOkLogo.click();
});
```

Another way is to wait until the upload progress bar reaches 100% by manually writing own ExpectedCondition to wait for. Here's how -

```
browser.wait(function(){
    return $('.percentage').getText().then(function(percent){
        return percent === '100 %'; //return true only if percentage is 100%
    });
}, 10000).then(function(){
    uploadButtonOkLogo.click();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That did it thankyou.  The last EC will be helpful too